# I get strange characters when performing AES decryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt an AES-ECB 128 encrypted string. That string was not encrypted with Java, I receive it as an input in Java and I want to decrypt it.

I've encrypted the message "0123456789012345" in Arduino with AESLib

```
  uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  char data[] = "0123456789012345"; //16 chars == 16 bytes
  aes128_enc_single(key, data);
```

The string in encrypted form is "1425EC9B5D983FF7DF45A4A8089E69FC".

That's what I do in java to decrypt it:

```
private static byte[] key = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15};

 public static String decrypt()
   {

       byte[] info= hexStrToByteArray("1425EC9B5D983FF7DF45A4A8089E69FC"); 
       try
       {
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPADDING");
           final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
           byte[] decryptedResult= cipher.doFinal(info);
           String result = new String(result, "UTF-8");
           return result;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();

       }
       return null;
   }


  private static byte[] hexStrToByteArray(String hex) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(hex.length() / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
            String output = hex.substring(i, i + 2);
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
            baos.write(decimal);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

what I get from this function is: .1�@JY�y�ғv�

I guess is a problem of encodings. How can I get the result of the decryption in a readable form?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a) the key (assuming it's a non-sensitive test key), b) your `hexStrToByteArray` function, and c) some details about how it was encrypted?

Comment: If you decrypt to gibberish the key or data is incorrect or at least incorrectly applied to the decryption function.

Comment: Sorry, I've added more info in the main message

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? `String result = new String(result, "UTF-8");` shouldn't even compile; you mean `decryptedResult` as the first parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is incorrect.

On the encryption side you have:

```
uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
```

On the decryption side you have:

```
private static byte[] key = {
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15};
```

`0x12` is not the same as `12`. You confused hexadecimal with decimal in your literals. On the decryption side you mean:

```
private static byte[] key = { 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
```

Or:

```
private static byte[] key = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };
```

By the way your original data is us-ascii not utf-8; doesn't really make a difference here and isn't part of the problem, but you should use us-ascii on the decryption side too to be safe.